# multiple aggregate functions with sails await function dose not return result values

Tags: mongodb, ecmascript-6, async-await, sails.js

My code requires to run multiple aggregate functions and combine the result of each aggregate calls to make final result dataset.

I am using await so as my first query complete to combine all result but not getting results and view is rendered before query execution.

```
  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
  var users = await Logger.native(function(err, collection) {
        collection.aggregate([.......], function(err, results){
            return results;
        })
  })
  console.log(users)

  var users2 = await Logger.native(function(err, collection) {
        collection.aggregate([.......], function(err, results){
            return results;
        })
  })
  console.log(users2)

  return exits.success({results: {"user": users, "emp": users2});
```

The above code is giving undefined users and user2 value. Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just await callback style function and expect result.
To make this work you will need to wrap it inside promise and then await.

```
fn: async function(inputs, exits) {
        var users = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Logger.native(function(err, collection) {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                collection.aggregate([.......], function(err, results) {
                    if (err) return reject(err)
                    resolve(results)
                })
            })
        })
        console.log(users)

        var users2 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            await Logger.native(function(err, collection) {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                collection.aggregate([.......], function(err, results) {
                    if (err) return reject(err)
                    resolve(results);
                })
            })
        })
        console.log(users2)

        return exits.success({results: {"user": users, "emp": users2});
```

Handle callback errors by returning reject(err) and resolve needed data when you get results using resolve(results)